# java.io.IOException: Unable to write on channel java.nio.channels.SocketChannel in Play Framework

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework-2.2, asynchttpclient

I'm trying to upload a byte array to a remote WS with multipart/form-data in play! framework using Scala. My code is:

```
    //create byte array from file
    val myFile = new File(pathName)
    val in = new FileInputStream(myFile)
    val myByteArray = new Array[Byte](audioFile.length.toInt)
    in.read(audioByteArray)
    in.close()    

    // create parts 
    val langPart = new StringPart("lang", "pt")
    val taskPart = new StringPart("task","echo")
    val audioPart = new ByteArrayPart("sbytes", "myFilename", myByteArray, "default/binary", "UTF-8")

    val client: AsyncHttpClient = WS.client
    val request = client.preparePost(RemoteWS)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
                        .addBodyPart(audioPart)
                        .addBodyPart(taskPart)
                        .addBodyPart(langPart).build()
    val result = Promise[Response]()

    // execute request 
    client.executeRequest(request, new AsyncCompletionHandler[AHCResponse]{
      override def onCompleted(response: AHCResponse): AHCResponse = {
        result.success(Response(response))
        response
      }
      override def onThrowable(t: Throwable) {
        result.failure(t)
      }
    })

    // handle async response
    result.future.map(result =>{
      Logger.debug("response: " + result.getAHCResponse.getResponseBody("UTF-8"))
    })
```

Every time I execute this request, it throws this exception:

**java.io.IOException: Unable to write on channel java.nio.channels.SocketChannel**

The remote server is OK, I can make sucessfull requests using for example Postman.

I'm using Play Framework:

**play 2.2.3 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.8.0_05)**

Version of AsyncHttpClient:

**com.ning:async-http-client:1.7.18**

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, how did you manage to fix it ?